# How to get transaction id after successful subscription

Tags: laravel, braintree, laravel-cashier

I am working on a platform offering services. When creating a new subscription, a new transaction for the first billing is created. How can I access the transactions id?

I have a form with Braintree's Drop-in UI and my backend looks currently like this:

```
if (!auth()->user()->subscribed('main')) {
     $subscription = auth()->user()->newSubscription('main', 'membership-monthly')->create($request->payment_method_nonce, []);
     dd($subscription);
}
```

This successfully creates a new subscription!

Now I want to access this subscription's first billing transaction's id. 
[image]
How can I achieve this?

Comment: what about $subscription->id ??

Comment: This is not the id I need. This is the id of the subscription in my local database. What I need is the id of the transaction which is different.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: I'm currently using the stripe_id which is returned by create() and it can be used to search in stripe dashboard which is sufficient as it functions as ref for the record in stripe system

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you should provide a second parameter to create function,
try this:

```
if (!auth()->user()->subscribed('main')) {
    $payload = array();
    $subscription = auth()
         ->user()
         ->newSubscription('main', 'membership-monthly')
         ->create($request->payment_method_nonce, $payload);
    dd($subscription);
    dd($payload);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Laravel Cashier [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/billing#braintree-configuration) the database schema looks like this:

```
Schema::create('subscriptions', function ($table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('braintree_id');
    $table->string('braintree_plan');
    $table->integer('quantity');
    $table->timestamp('trial_ends_at')->nullable();
    $table->timestamp('ends_at')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I would assume to get the subscription in your case would be similar to `$subscription->braintree_id`

Answer (score -1):

If you have an relation between subscription and transactions you need access so :

```
foreach($subscription->transactions() as $transaction){
   //here you access yo transactions id
   dd($transaction);
}
```

I hope that i could help you

Comment: Sadly there isn't a transactions() method. Trying $subscription->transactions returns an empty array as well.